pythonnet with WPF App (.NET Framework 4.8) - Could not load python.dll exception a
I would like to build a Visual Studio C# .NET Framework app using the Python.NET (pythonnet) package to call Python code. I.e. Visual C# provides the GUI and Python code the functionality.  The Python.NET package was installed into the Visual C# using NuGet.
The sample "Python.NET (pythonnet)" script is from (https://medium.com/@hanxuyang0826/triggering-python-code-from-c-a-practical-guide-84b17d593dc6#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20simplest%20ways,Process%60%20class%20to%20run%20it). When calling the Python code from a Visual C# Console application, it runs without issue with two additions: 1) setting "Runtime.PythonDLL" at the start and 2) setting a flag for a binary formatter at the end:
public void ExecutePythonCode() { 
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll";

// Initialize the Python engine
PythonEngine.Initialize();

using (Py.GIL())
{
    // Import the Python file
    dynamic calculatorModule = Py.Import("pythonExample");

    // Create an instance of the Calculator class
    dynamic calculator = calculatorModule.Calculator();

    // Call the AddInPython method
    int result = calculator.AddInPython(5, 10);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result of adding in Python: {result}");
}

// Shutdown the Python engine
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/8.0/binaryformatter-disabled
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization", true);
PythonEngine.Shutdown();

}`
However when attempting to run the code from a .NET Framework 4.8 app, the following runtime exception occurs at the PythonEngine.Initialize() statement:

DllNotFoundException: Could not load C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll

I have tested with adding system environment variables for PYTHONHOME, PYTHONNET_PYDLL, and PYTHONPATH (as seen in other posts about a similar exception), but the result was the same.
Does anyone know why the .NET Framework App cannot find the python37.dll file, given that the Console App has no issues?
